# make hitTest(_:with:) function return UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a view that added some UIButton.
given a CGPoint how can I get the button laid on.

sample code

```
let location = tapRecognizer.location(in: view)
    let tapView = view.hitTest(location, with: nil)
```

the code below won't work how can I get the UIbutton form tapView

```
    if let button = tapView as? UIButton {
        print("text")
    }
```

help appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do? Know which button was tapped? Invoke the action of another button through a gesture recognizer?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I m trying to know which button was taped and there are so many buttons... knowing which button to add some effect when .touchupinside

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use [target-action](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html) for this? You can have multiple controls with the same "action". When one of them triggers, they will pass themselves as the "sender".

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist because I’m not calling target-action I want the button I pressed change some run time attribute when .touchupinside state

Comment: Assign one target-action for all of the buttons, assign different tags for each button. Then you can check the tag for the button that is tapped on the assigned target-action.

Answer (score 0):

While adding button to the view add target to the button and assign a different tag to each button and perform action according to the tag

For the this purpose you can use the gesture delegate like 

**Example:-**

```
 func addGestureOnContentView () -> Void {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ExploreViewController.hideTableView))
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
```

Now use gesture delegate like :-

```
 func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
            if (touch.view?.isDescendant(of: UIButton))! {
                return false //Perform your task in this block
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: tks...but I'm not using button to perform action..just want to get the subView as UIbutton

Comment: @jin check the updated answer, hope this will help you